# Dynamic Values in 'IN' operator

Tags: mysql, sql, where-in

I have a select statement in which the WHERE clause's IN operator. The query works properly as long as some values are passed to question mark (passed from java program). But when there are no values passed, I get a syntax error.

```
select
    this_.categoryAddressMapId as category1_1_0_,
    this_.categoryId as categoryId1_0_,
    this_.addressId as addressId1_0_
from
     icapcheckmyphotos.category_address_map this_ <br>
where
     this_.addressId in (
            ?
     )
```

When there are no parameters passed, I need null set. Please suggest how to modify the where clause. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's required that you have at least one value in the brackets, e.g. `where foo in ()` is not legal sql. it has to be at least `where foo in (bar)`. there's nothing you do to bypass this restriction without writing dynamic sql, or putting in at least one value you KNOW must be present.

Comment: Should the Java program even be invoking this query if there is nothing to be gotten from it? Seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your java program.  Your choices are to not run the query if there are no addressIds, or ensure that it passes at least one value.  If addressId is an integer field, pass -1 or something like that.  Personally, I like the first option but it depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

how about doing sometiong like

```
where (? is null) OR this_.addressId in ( ?  )
```

you may need to add some special treatment to the first part of the OR if your columns does accept NULLS

Answer (score 0):

//pseudo code
...

```
WHERE 1
if(!null) {
   AND this_.addressId in ('stuff')
}
```